# JQuery mobile load versus change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, dom

What is the difference between JQuery mobile pagecontainer's ["load"](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecontainer/#method-load) versus ["change"](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecontainer/#method-change) functions and what is intended usage of each? I'm not interested in how the events are for each but rather what does each to do the DOM.

I've been using change to switch pages; but I'm getting some "unexpected" behavior.

Here's my scenario. There is a light page that is presented to the user for login. After logging in, I call "change" to get a page that loads a heavy page (a dashboard). In that dashboard page, I've got a button hooked up that has JQ "change" to a dialog page. When the user confirms the dialog, JQ "changes" to the dashboard page.

The issue is that upon changing back to the dashboard page the dashboard UI is all new. For example, say a user flipped a flipswitch in the dashboard, upon returning to the dashboard the user finds the switch isn't flipped.

After inspecting the DOM I see that when switching to the dialog page, JQ removes the dashboard page from the DOM and inserts the dialog. When switching back to the dashboard, JQ removes the dialog from the DOM and inserts the dashboard. Thus the fresh UI; but if the behavior is such, what is the intent of the "reload" property of each method if "change" chucks the page out of the DOM?

I tried changing things to using "load" and load inserts the DOM in but doesn't make it visible. I can't figure out how to use change to make it visible...

Comment: You're using _Single Page Model_ with DOM cache disabled. Whenever you move to an _external_ page, hidden page is removed from DOM that's why you it looks fresh when you navigate back to it. `load` loads page in background w/out changing to it, `change` loads and then navigate to loaded page/url. http://jqmtricks.wordpress.com/2014/05/23/jquery-mobile-page-events-extra/

Comment: Ah, thanks @Omar. So, I tested out 'load' and see that it doesn't kick out the other page. How can I switch to that loaded page without kicking out the previous page? 'change' doesn't seem to do it.

Comment: you need to keep that page in DOM by adding `data-dom-cache="true"` attribute to page div of that page.

Comment: Thank-you so much. I should have read further in the docs.